# How to set focus on inputs after creating DOM with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have 2 `<form>`:

```
<form action="">
  <h3>Mail</h3>
  <div class="flex-row js-mail-change__parent">
    <p>mail@mail.com</p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="js-mail-change">Edit</a>
  </div>
</form>

<form action="">
  <h3>Phone</h3>
  <div class="flex-row js-phone-change__parent">
    <p>+7 (903) 999 99 99</p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="js-phone-change">Edit</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

And I create DOM on click in `<form>`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.js-mail-change').on('click', function () {
        $('.js-mail-change__parent')
            .html('<input type="email" name="email" value="">' +
                  '<input type="submit" value="Submit">');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.js-phone-change').on('click', function () {
        $('.js-phone-change__parent')
            .html('<input type="tel" name="phone" value="">' +
                  '<input type="submit" value="Submit">');
    });
});
```

How to set focus on `<input>` that needed due to ui?
Attribute `autofocus` doesn't work on two fields which logical.

Any variants to set it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) method

```
$('.js-mail-change').on('click', function() {
  var js = $('.js-mail-change__parent');
  var mail = $(this).prev('p').text();
  js.html('<input type="email" name="email" value="' + mail + '">' +
    '<input type="submit" value="Submit">');

  js.children(':input:first').focus();
});
```

```js
$('.js-mail-change').on('click', function() {
  var js = $('.js-mail-change__parent');
  var mail = $(this).prev('p').text();
  js.html('<input type="email" name="email" value="' + mail + '">' +
    '<input type="submit" value="Submit">');

  js.children(':input:first').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Mail</h3>
<div class="flex-row js-mail-change__parent">
  <p>mail@mail.com</p>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="js-mail-change">Edit</a>
</div>
```

References

1. [`:input` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)
2. [`:first` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)
3. [`.get(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

Answer (score 1):

When creating an element, save it as a variable and then use `el.focus()`. This way you don't need to search through DOM again.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('.js-mail-change').on('click', function () {
        var emailEl = $('<input type="email" name="email" value="">'),
            submitEl = $('<input type="submit" value="Submit">');
        $('.js-mail-change__parent').append(emailEl, submitEl);
        emailEl.focus();
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('.js-phone-change').on('click', function () {
        var telEl = $('<input type="tel" name="phone" value="">'),
            submitEl = $('<input type="submit" value="Submit">');
        $('.js-phone-change__parent').append(telEl, submitEl);
        telEl.focus();
    });
});
```

Small example in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvkzd282/).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot to create jQuery objects. I updated my post and also added a link to jsFiddle example.

Comment: thanks, I'll change `.append()` on `.html()` and it has to be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Some insights : https://api.jquery.com/focus/

```
//your input element
var emailEl = '<input type="email" name="email" value="">';
//trigger focus event on it.
$(emailEl).focus();
```